# Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome on high end computer (NVMe)?

Tags: dual-boot, firmware, nvme

I'm about to build a heck of a PC and was thinking of dual booting with Windows, but, i just might "single boot" it only with Ubuntu (17.04 Gnome that i'm currently dual booting with Win10, as we speak)
Specs are:
I7 6900K
64 GB LPX 3200 MHz RAM (Corsair Vengeance 4*16GB)
ASUS X99 Deluxe II
ASUS 1080 ROG Strix (Not the OC version)
Samsung 960 Pro 1 TB (Boot drive)
Samsung 850 Pro 2 TB (Storage)
All wrapped up in a Fractal Design Blackout edition case

I was told to use Windows at first, due to the fact that my system drive (NVMe) had poor support in Linux and at least update the firmware for my 960 Pro in Windows, to get it rockin.

But, is that the fact, or could I just install Samsung Proprietary Magician in Ubuntu, to upgrade the firmware? 
If so, I'll ditch Windows completely.